# Unable to list repositories in sagemaker project due to stack not existing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

The following is the error message I get:

```
Error listing project repositories. Error message: Error listing resources in a stack. Error message: Stack with id SC-xxxxxxxxxxxx-pp-xxxxxxxxxxxxx does not exist.
```

I checked, and a stack was created with the code commit repository but with a different id. I'm wondering where this stack with different id is coming from. Is this a permissions issue?

Edit: This is a custom sagemaker project created from this cloud formation template(which is a service catalog product).

```
---
Parameters:
  SageMakerProjectId:
    Description: "Service-generated id of the project"
    NoEcho: true
    Type: String
  SageMakerProjectName:
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*"
    Description: "Name of the project"
    MaxLength: 32
    MinLength: 1
    NoEcho: true
    Type: String
Resources:
  ModelBuildCodeCommitRepository:
    Properties:
      Code:
        BranchName: main
        S3:
          Bucket: sagemaker-servicecatalog-seedcode-us-west-2
          Key: toolchain/image-build-model-building-workflow-v1.0.zip
      RepositoryDescription:
        ? "Fn::Sub"
        : "SageMaker Model building workflow infrastructure as code for the Project ${SageMakerProjectName}"
      RepositoryName:
        ? "Fn::Sub"
        : "${SageMakerProjectName}-${SageMakerProjectId}-modelbuild"
    Type: "AWS::CodeCommit::Repository"
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What Project are you using? Is this a custom project or a SageMaker provided template?

If you use this API, do you see the repositories? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/list-code-repositories.html

Comment: If I use the api I see a former repository but not the current one that I want.

Comment: @KiritThadaka can you check out my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914046/sagemaker-project-successfully-creates-but-there-are-no-linked-pipelines-or-repo/72939274#72939274?