# Sagemaker Project successfully creates but there are no linked pipelines or repositories

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

I created a sagemaker project with a terraform template which successfully created with a stack successfully created and associated with it. However, there is no repository associated or pipeline associated with the sagemaker project despite there being both in the cloudformation template I used. Can someone help with this?

Is there a way to manually link a sagemaker project with a code commit repository? I see that succesfully linked repositories have the tag: `sagemaker:project-name` with the correct project name.

Comment: Without terraform code it is almost impossible.

Comment: I think you should tag your pipelines and the tag name should be the project name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different cloudformation template fixed the issue. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, i can say this(obviously), your template has integration issues. The usual suspect is:

1. IAM permissions. Check if the execution role used to deploy the template and create the project in SageMaker Studio, has permissions to create the codecommit repositories or not.